# Android: Bitmap appears smaller after setting with setBackgroundDrawable

Tags: java, android, android-layout, bitmap, android-canvas

I have a weird problem where using a combination of drawBitmap and setBackgroundDrawable makes my image appear 2x smaller than it actually is.

Below is my code that creates a new bitmap and canvas. It then draws the bitmap on the canvas and puts the new bitmap as the background of an existing layout. I must use this method because I am going to manipulate the canvas later on.

```
Bitmap left = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resID);      
// Create a temporary bitmap
Bitmap tempBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        left.getWidth(),
        left.getHeight(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);           
Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(tempBitmap);         
//Draw bitmap on canvas
tempCanvas.drawBitmap(left, 0, 0, null);
background.setBackgroundDrawable(tempBitmap);
```

I tried using `tempCanvas.scale(2, 2);` and this does scale the "pixels" back to normal but it doesn't scale the rectangle.

If I use `background.setBackgroundResource(resID);` the background image appears at the correct size, which rules out any problems with my MDPI/HDPI/XHDPI folders.

Why is my background image appearing at a smaller scale when setting it with `setBackgroundDrawable()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem with

```
tempCanvas.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to AndroidManifest

```
<supports-screens
            android:resizeable="true"
            android:normalScreens="true"
            android:largeScreens="true"
            android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Comment: Well this didn't fix the problem but it did make me check if the problem was on an MDPI device. And apparently it isn't. So it does have something to do with the canvas density(?). Still not sure how to fix it though!